# Catch a Spinner selection with a Button?

Tags: android, button, spinner

As the title says, i have a Spinner with just a couple of options and a button. I didnt declared any Listener for the spinner, instead of that, what i want is use the button and perform different actions depending on the spinner selected option.

So, i declared a handler in the button option "android:onClick", but once there, i dont know how to access the option selected in the Spinner.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call getSelectedItemPosition() on the Spinner. Also you may look at Spinner's reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html. Click on "Exapand all" in the top right corner and search for "getselect" for other ways to get selected item info.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I've been reading the spinner's reference before, but probably between all those methods i just didnt realize about the getSelectedPosition  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner.setAdapter(this.adapter); 
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,View view,int i,long l){
        //TODO handle the event
    }
});
```

use the above code to catch the selected spinner optin with a button